# Search and replace with a regular expression in vi?

Tags: regular-expression, string, vi

I would like to replace a string with regular expression that appears in multiple lines with the character "x":

The problem is to replace words with the x in front that has an integer after the x, such as in a file that contains:

```
x44name
xjanname
x50name
```

For example:

```
:1,2s/x[0-9]name/num/g
```

Would I need to use sed or some other command to search and replace the word?

The following error occurs:

```
E486: Pattern not found: x[0-9]name
```

Comment: your substitution will replace one (1) digit, your sample line have two (2). your substitution is ok thou, try `%s/x[0-9][0-9]name/num/` (by the way no need for `g` if you have only one pattern per line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can have any number of digits (including 0) you should do

```
:%s/x[0-9]*name/num/g
```

if it's always two

```
:%s/x[0-9][0-9]name/num/g
```

of course you can also use \d instead of [0-9]

```
:%s/x\d*name/num/g
```

- `%s` means search the whole file
- `s` means just search the current line
- `g` means all matches in a given line
- no g means only the first match per line is replaced

Comment: So the asterisk symbol `*` is essential for finding all numbers from the list?

Comment: It matches 0 or more times.  You could also instead use a + symbol.  That will match 1 or more times.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, and "num" it is number that next in order after "x", catch this out:

```
:%s/x\([0-9]\)/\1/g
```